# Androidx OnBackPressedDispatcher - how to consume the back button press

Tags: androidx, onbackpressed

I would like the `onBackPressedDispatcher` to absorb the back button press event. Sometimes but I don't see an option for it. Whats happening is that we are just today trying to upgrade to `onBackPressedDispatcher` in androidX but we have already overridden `onBackPressd` in activity. so when our `onBackPressedDispatcher` calls `OnBackPressedCallback` afterwards there is also a call to activities onBackPressed override. we don't want that. the `onBackpressed` should be consumed on the spot. here is what I have so far:

```
const val TAG = "MyTag"

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first)
        MyTester(this)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        Log.v(TAG, "Activities class back button Pressed")

    }

    inner class MyTester(var activity: AppCompatActivity) {
        init {
            addBackCB()
        }

        fun addBackCB() {
            var callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                    Log.v(TAG, "inner class MyTester back button")
                }
            }
            activity.onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(activity, callback);
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints the following:

```
V/MyTag: inner class MyTester back button
V/MyTag: Activities class back button Pressed
```

If I don't call `super.onBackPressed()` then the dispatcher does not even work. it needs that call.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is because the `OnBackPressedDispatcher` is called in `ComponentActivity.onBackPressed()`, if you look at the source code:

```
    @Override
    @MainThread
    public void onBackPressed() {
        mOnBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed();
    }
```

So you'll never reach your callback if you override `onBackPressed` and never call the super method. I think the whole idea behind `OnBackPressedDispatcher` is that you shouldn't have to override `Activity.onBackPressed` if you want your fragments to intercept back presses. This is mentioned [in one of the guides](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back#activity_onbackpressed).

If you really want your activity to handle the back press, you can try something like this in your override:

```
    if (onBackPressedDispatcher.hasEnabledCallbacks()) {
      // There's an active callback; let the fragment handle it
      super.onBackPressed()
    } else {
      // Do your activity's back press handling here
    }
```

Be careful doing this, though. After trying it myself, you might find that `hasEnabledCallbacks` will return true even when you haven't added any callbacks yourself. This is because your `FragmentManager` has its own back press callback that's going to be enabled whenever `backStackEntryCount > 0`. I'm not sure if there's a quick workaround for that.

Comment: hi, yes this is working but i have little question here when i backprress from nested fragment it working fine now i am on firstactivity now backpress open blank screen

Comment: @SunilChaudhary, I'm not good at Kotlin, but I guess you can use an intent to redirect to the desired page maybe? At least this is what I've done for my project.