# onBackPressed() is deprecated. What is the alternative?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, deprecation-warning, android-tiramisu

I have upgraded `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to `33`.

I am now getting a warning telling me that [onBackPressed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed()) is deprecated.

I see suggestions to use [android.window.OnBackInvokedCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/window/OnBackInvokedCallback) or [androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedCallback) to handle back navigation instead. Can anyone can help me use the updated method?

#### Example

[image: onBackPressedDeprecated]

#### Use Case

I use `if (isTaskRoot) {}` inside the [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed()) method to check whether the activity is the last one on the activity stack.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (isTaskRoot) { // Check whether this activity is last on the activity stack. (Check whether this activity opened from a Push Notification.)
        startActivity(Intent(mContext, Dashboard::class.java))
        finish()
    } else {
        finishWithResultOK()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're just calling `super.onBackPressed()`, then you can just remove the method entirely as you're not writing any custom back behavior. If you *are* writing custom back behavior, show your code.

Comment: @ianhanniballake , I am using `if (isTaskRoot) {}` inside `onBackPressed()` to check activity is last on the activity-stack. I have also updated the question.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that at all on any API level. Please include your code.

Comment: The product detail page is opening clicking on the push notification. If the app is closed, now the user enters in product-detail-page clicking on push notification. Then clicking onBackpress, the user should not directly exit the app. for this case I use `onBackPressed().`

Comment: Did you figure out the `isTaskRoot` conditional? Most the answer seem to be very focused on trivial use-cases.

Comment: @TWiStErRob, Yes. `isTaskRoot` it's conditional. Whether the activity already has back stack activity or not.

Comment: Yeah, I got that, what I'm asking is how to do the conditional, at which point do you have the `if`? Because based on the dispatcher's code, it'll call the first enabled callback, and then stop.

Comment: To understand in detail:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/onbackpressed-deprecated-in-targetsdkversion-33-b4c27096bafe

Comment: I am calling onBackPressed() to put the app into the background - that is my customized behavior

Answer (score 131, accepted):

According your API level register:

- [`onBackInvokedDispatcher.registerOnBackInvokedCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/window/OnBackInvokedDispatcher#registerOnBackInvokedCallback(int,%20android.window.OnBackInvokedCallback)) for API level 33+
- [`onBackPressedDispatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher) callback for backword compatibility "API level 13+"

This requires to at least use `appcompat:1.6.0-alpha03`; the current is `1.6.0-alpha04`:

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha04'
```

```
// kotlin
import androidx.activity.addCallback

if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastT()) {
    onBackInvokedDispatcher.registerOnBackInvokedCallback(
        OnBackInvokedDispatcher.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    ) {
        // Back is pressed... Finishing the activity
        finish()
    }
} else {
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this /* lifecycle owner */, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            // Back is pressed... Finishing the activity
            finish()
        }
    })
}

// ====================================================
/* Or for lambda simplicity: */
// ====================================================
if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastT()) {
    onBackInvokedDispatcher.registerOnBackInvokedCallback(
        OnBackInvokedDispatcher.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    ) {
        // Back is pressed... Finishing the activity
        finish()
    }
} else {
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this /* lifecycle owner */) {
        // Back is pressed... Finishing the activity
        finish()
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE:

Thanks to @ianhanniballake comment; you can just use `OnBackPressedDispatcher` even in API level 33+

> The OnBackPressedDispatcher is already going to be using the Android T specific API internally when using Activity 1.6+,

So, you can just do:

```
// kotlin
import androidx.activity.addCallback

onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this /* lifecycle owner */, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        // Back is pressed... Finishing the activity
        finish()
    }
})

// ====================================================
/* Or for lambda simplicity: */
// ====================================================
onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this /* lifecycle owner */) {
    // Back is pressed... Finishing the activity
    finish()
}
```

```
// java
import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback;

getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    @Override
    public void handleOnBackPressed() {
        // Back is pressed... Finishing the activity
        finish();
    }
});
```

Note that you shouldn't override the `onBackPressed()` as that will make the `onBackPressedDispatcher` callback not to fire; check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57897677/9851608) for clarifying that.

Comment: The `OnBackPressedDispatcher` is already going to be using the Android T specific API internally when using Activity 1.6+, so there's absolutely no reason to ever use the Android T APIs directly - you can just use the `OnBackPressedDispatcher` on all API levels.

Comment: The problem I see here is now you have two ways to handle back press which is kinda messy. Is there any way to restrict overriding of the old `onBackPressed`?

Comment: How can I invoke `OnBackPressedCallback` `handleOnBackPressed` programmatically, say I have a button that needs to call `onBackPressed()` programmatically?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS  AFAIK, still `onBackPressed()` exposed to developers; at some newer API this shouldn't be true; but handling both simultaneously isn't that right as the note left at the end of the answer.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS For calling `onBackPressed()` I'd rather prefer to pop the back stack; you can `finish()` the activity, or for navigation components using `navController.popBackStack()`

Comment: I get `Cannot resolve symbol 'addCallback'` when trying `import androidx.activity.addCallback`.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Have you upgraded to `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha04'`?

Comment: @Zain Yes. I also tried with the newer `1.6.0-rc01`. I also get `Cannot resolve symbol 'onBackPressedDispatcher'`. Maybe it is the Kotlin code that I am translating wrongly to Java...?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Just updated the answer with java snippet. Please have a look

Comment: Access the callback function by `onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()`

Comment: @Zain With your updated java code I can import now, yet I still get error: `Cannot resolve method 'getOnBackPressedDispatcher' in 'FullScreenBrowser'.`

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Could you please open a question for that providing your gradle dependencies it seems that something not clear; I just test it out, it worked even in java.

Comment: @Zain It was my fault: I was extending Activity instead of AppCompatActivity. Sorry!

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Wow it's a nightmare! Congrats!

Comment: If you're in a fragment, there is no "finish()".  If you addCallback, but want to continue the normal back behavior, the only method I found is to disable the callback and hit back again.  So from within the callback:    
this.isEnabled = false;    
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed();

Comment: Dont forget to add ` android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"` to <application> manifest otherwiseit won;t work for newer API's

Comment: Another answer suggesting using `finish()` to destroy activity... Android 12/13 doesn't destroy the activity on back pressed right away, it keeps in memory for a while and you suggest to call `finish()` to kill instantly on back press...

Answer (score 142):

Replace onBackPressed() with below code.

```
onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
```

Comment: Voilà, I'm using targetSdk 33

Comment: For fragment - requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()

Comment: Xamarin code: OnBackPressedDispatcher.OnBackPressed();

Comment: This requires the Activity to be androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.

Answer (score 45):

***With a combination of top answers. Here is a solution :***

**1. When you need to press the back button, copy this :**

*Note: it will automatically destroy your activity.*

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
}
```

**2. When you need to handle the back button pressed, copy this :**

```
onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object: OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        // Whatever you want
        // when back pressed
        println("Back button pressed")
        finish()
    }
})
```

Comment: can't resolve onBackPressedDispatcher

Comment: Maybe something went wrong with your code. Isn't that Kotlin?

Comment: Another answer suggesting using `finish()` to destroy activity... Android 12/13 doesn't destroy the activity on back pressed right away, it keeps in memory for a while and you suggest to call `finish()` to kill instantly on back press...

Comment: I've checked by overriding onDestroy method in Kotlin Native code, and it printed 'destroyed.' However, I'm not sure if it's functioning correctly in Compose code.

Answer (score 42):

Simply replace

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed() // Replace this deprecated line
}
```

with

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() // with this line
}
```

### Update

Given that `override fun onBackPressed()` is deprecated, replace it with the following code:

```
onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object: OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        println("Back button pressed")
        // Code that you need to execute on back press, e.g. finish()
  }
})
```

Add the above code to an activity lifecycle function like `onCreate(savedInstanceState:)`.

Comment: 'The above code we need to write inside some method like onCreate() function.' This is what I was missing, thank you..

Comment: `/ Code that you need to execute on back press, e.g. finish()` - Android 12/13 doesn't destroy the activity on back pressed right away, it keeps in memory for a while and you suggest to call `finish()` to kill instantly on back press...

Answer (score 14):

In **Kotlin**, this way is working

1- Remove `onBackPressed()`

2- below `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` add these lines:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
        onBackInvokedDispatcher.registerOnBackInvokedCallback(
            OnBackInvokedDispatcher.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        ) {
           
            exitOnBackPressed()
        }
    } else {
        onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
            this,
            object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                  
                    Log.i("TAG", "handleOnBackPressed: Exit")
                    exitOnBackPressed()
                }
            })
    }
```

3- Define a new function for handling

```
fun exitOnBackPressed() {
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder

class SampleActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_sample) {

    private val onBackPressedCallback: OnBackPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            showAppClosingDialog()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, onBackPressedCallback)
    }

    private fun showAppClosingDialog() {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
            .setTitle("Warning")
            .setMessage("Do you really want to close the app?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ -> finish() }
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [onBackPressedDispatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher)

```
onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
         
    }
})
```

in here "this" means the lifeCycleOwner

Answer (score 7):

For Kotlin Users:

If you are trying to call the Default Native Back Button function using the 'new' way, you can use the code bellow inside your Activity.

```
this@MyActivity.onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
```

example:

```
myCloseButton.setOnClickListener { this@MyActivity.onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() }
```

The example above sets a click function inside a button, to make the button act like the Native Android Back Button.

However, if you want to customize the onBackPressedDispatcher, you can follow the example bellow, always inside your Activity, because this behaviour needs an Activity Context to work.

Example of Customized OnBackPressed:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
   val callback: OnBackPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallBack(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            //ToDo Implement your custom event here    
        }
    }

    this@MyActivity.onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this@MyActivity, callback)
}
```

The expected result is to make any onBackPressedDispatcher event to do whatever you want, or do nothing at all. But this is not recommended, since your user might get stuck in a screen, without being able to use his Phone's Back Button. Because of that, avoid leaving handleOnBackPressed override empty. So try something like this:

```
override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
    this@MyActivity.finish()
}
```

Comment: A little more detail would be nice

Comment: I add some details to this answer. I hope you guys can make good use. Feel free to ask any questions inside this Thread Answer.

Answer (score 5):

use onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() instead of super.onBackPressed()

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
  onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the OnBackInvokedCallback

[image: OnBackInvokedCallback] as described in the documentation and follow this [guide here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/handling-gesture-back-navigation#0) to update your code

Answer (score 3):

Bonus: To close DrawerLayout when onBackPressed use like below (according to [this I/O talk](https://youtu.be/Elpqr5xpLxQ?t=545)),

```
val callback = onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, false) {
    binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
}
            
binding.drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(object : DrawerListener {  
        
    override fun onDrawerOpened(drawerView: View) {
        callback.isEnabled = true
    }
        
    override fun onDrawerClosed(drawerView: View) {
        callback.isEnabled = false
    }

    override fun onDrawerSlide(drawerView: View, slideOffset: Float) = Unit    
    override fun onDrawerStateChanged(newState: Int) = Unit
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the extension function to implement OnBackPressedCallback in activity.

```
fun AppCompatActivity.addOnBackPressedDispatcher(onBackPressed: () -> Unit = { finish() }) {
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
        this,
        object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                onBackPressed.invoke()
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Usage:

```
addOnBackPressedDispatcher {
    //doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Are there any code samples for Xamarin C#?  I have seen one for .NET but it used a private class and I couldn't get it to compile.  I have tried installing some new Nuget classes, but that just became a rathole.  Is there a simple way to replace my OnBackPressed calls?  Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73619091/using-onbackpressedcallback-in-xamarin

Comment: The function should better be called `addOnBackPressedCallback()`, because that is what it does. There is only one Dispatcher which handles all the callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Java then here's a way I'm doing it.

```
// Creating a global variable
private final OnBackPressedDispatcher onBackPressedDispatcher = getOnBackPressedDispatcher();
```

```
// In your onCreate method
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

   // Add callback listener
   onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
       @Override
       public void handleOnBackPressed() {
           // Handle onback pressed
       }
   });
}
```

Then if you want to force call onBackPressed you can do it using:

```
mBtnBack.setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed());
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by simply adding an extension to `AppCompatActivity`:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.onBackButtonPressed(callback: (() -> Unit)? = null){
    val onBackPressed: OnBackPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            callback?.let { callback() } ?: run { finish() }
        }
    }
    this.onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, onBackPressed)
}
```

So I can use it by calling "onBackButtonPressed" in two ways

1- Implement back pressed to finish activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // implement back pressed
    onBackButtonPressed()
}
```

2- Handle back pressed clicks:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // implement back pressed
    onBackButtonPressed {
        // handle back pressed click here,

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

first,we have to add a callback object because, `onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()` triggers a call to the currently added callbacks in reverse order in which they were added.
So after adding the callback only we should call the method `onBackPressed()`

The code (in kotlin) is as follows:

```
 onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this,object :OnBackPressedCallback(true){
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                Log.i("TAG","back has been called")
                finish()
            }
        })

onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
```

Answer (score 2):

Most answers are calling `finish()` when you want to close the activity. This works fine for most cases but in some situations this doesn't work. For example, in Android 13, when you press back on the last activity in the stack and return to the home screen, `onDestroy()` is not called immediately and app remains in memory. If you open up the app again right then, it starts from `onStart()`.

So, in some situations its better to let the system handle the closing of the app, or in the other words, let `super.onBackPressed()` happen.

To replace this

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if(showPopUpBeforeClosing){
        showDialog()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

do this -

```
onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        if (showPopUpBeforeClosing) {
            showDialog()
        } else {
            //Removing this callback
            remove()
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
})
```

If you add a callback to the `onBackPressedDispatcher`, and call `onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()`, it always calls `handleOnBackPressed()`. There is no method like onSuperBackPressed() or something to let the system know to handle the backPress on its own once you're done. If you don't add the callback, then the system does its own thing, but if you've added it, then calling onBackPress will invoke `handleOnBackPressed()`. So what we do is, once you're done handling the back-press, you `callback.remove()` the callback removes itself and now when you do `onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()`, it will not invoke `handleOnBackPressed()` and handle the back-press as the system would do, which is equivalent to `super.onBackPressed()`.

Comment: Pretty sure this is wrong. The system sees that the callback is enabled (as per the `true`) and thus can not play the predictive back navigation. You are solving the deprecation issue, but solving it wrongly... You should update the `isEnabled` property of the callback when you have a new value for `showPopUpBeforeClosing` (easiest if it's reactive/state-based). Code like `if (showPopUpBeforeClosing) {` should not exist in the new onBackPressedCallback world anymore.

Answer (score 2):

you can use onBackPressedDispatcher. Below an example:

```
val back = this.onBackPressedDispatcher
back.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true){
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        //println("back pressed")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To set up ability to override default behaviour:
(call `setupBackPressedHandling()` From Activity `onCreate()`):

```
  private fun setupBackPressedHandling() {
        onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            if (!backPressHandled())
                invokeDefaultBackPressedHandling()
        }
    }

open fun backPressHandled(): Boolean = false
```

Global extension function:

```
  fun AppCompatActivity.invokeDefaultBackPressedHandling(navController: NavController?) {
    when(navController) {
        null -> {
            if (!supportFragmentManager.isStateSaved && !supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate())
                finish()
        }
        else -> {
            if (!navController.popBackStack())
                finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like the back button handled you need this part in your onCreate() method of your activity. Don't forget to actually finish the activity in the handleOnBackPressed().

```
getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    @Override
    public void handleOnBackPressed() {
        //Add custom actions here (like before in onBackPressed())
        finish();
    }
});
```

If you have a up arrow inside your activity, this involves the method onSupportNavigateUp() for AppCompatActivity.

So you also need to handle this. Do it this way.

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    getOnBackPressedDispatcher().onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override the onDismiss() function for BottomSheets.

```
override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
   super.onDismiss(dialog)
   //TODO your logic.
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use like below,

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (v?.id) {
        R.id.iv_back -> onBackPressedMethod()
    }
}
```

and now create that method for handling back event

```
private fun onBackPressedMethod(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
        onBackInvokedDispatcher.registerOnBackInvokedCallback(
            OnBackInvokedDispatcher.PRIORITY_DEFAULT) {
               onBackPressed.invoke()
        }
    } else {
        onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
            this,
            object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                  onBackPressed.invoke()
                }
            })
    }
}
```

That's it!