# Why does onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() ignore animations?

Tags: android, navigation, deprecation-warning

There are [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72634225/onbackpressed-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative/75157418#75157418) that [try to address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72765170/onbackpresseddispatcher-onbackpressed-vs-backpressedcallback-handleonbackpress) `onBackPressed()` being deprecated.

The general answer seems to be: *"Replace it with `onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()`*. However, when I do that I *lose* animations. When I started an intent with a slide in/out animation, calling `Activity.onBackPressed()` will respect this animation, but `onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()` wont (it does some fading animation instead).

So how can I replace the deprecated `Activity.onBackPressed()` without losing custom activity animations?