# how to navigate back when toolbar home is clicked now that onBackPressed is deprecated in Android

Tags: android

My current Android project has the following code

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            super.onBackPressed()
            return true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```

e.g. when the toolbar home icon is clicked I call `onBackPressed()` and the user navigates to the previous location within the app.

`onBackPressed()` is now deprecated and I am informed I need to employ `getOnBackPressedDispatcher()`, I do not see how this dispatcher can replace my call to `onBackPressed()`.

what am I missing?

how should I refactor my code now that `onBackPressed()` is deprecated?

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72634975/2649154

Comment: @gioravered, that question isnt relevant to my case. that question concerns reacting to the back button being clicked. i need to programmatically call onBackPressed. when the toolbar home icon is clicked.