# Using OnBackPressedCallback in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to implement something similar to OnBackPressed() in a fragment in Xamarin, but the only solutions I found so far are for Java.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments) is one example in Java that does what I want:

```
OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "back pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
            // And when you want to go back based on your condition
            if (yourCondition) {
                this.setEnabled(false);
                requireActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    };
```

How could I go about converting that piece of code into C#?

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have anonymous classes in C#, so just create a class that inherits this abstract class and you're good:

```
public class HandleOnBackPressedCallback : OnBackPressedCallback
{
    public HandleOnBackPressedCallback(bool enabled) : base(enabled)
    {
    }

    public override void HandleOnBackPressed()
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context, "back pressed", ToastLength.Long).Show();

        // And when you want to go back based on your condition
        if (yourCondition)
        {
            this.setEnabled(false);
            requireActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

Create an interface for handling your event:

```
public interface IOnBackPressedHandler
{
    bool OnBackPressed();
}
```

In your activity (below is just an example) setup your interface callback as follows:

```
public class FragActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        Fragment fragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.yourFragmentId);
        if (!(fragment is IOnBackPressedHandler) || !((IOnBackPressedHandler)fragment).OnBackPressed()) {
            base.OnBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Finally, your fragment would look something like that:

```
public class SomeFragment : Fragment, IOnBackPressedHandler
{
    public bool OnBackPressed()
    {
        //Callbacks will be received here.
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can also make this method a part of your base Fragment mark it as virtual and then have all classes inherit this to keep overriding it.

Comment: Thanks for the conversion. How do I actually make the HandleOnBackPressed() method run though? I don't want to call the method directly, what I want is for that method to be called when the user pressed the back button in a fragment.

Here is the code I wrote in the fragment:

`HandleOnBackPressedCallBack callback = new HandleOnBackPressedCallback(true);`
`Activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher.AddCallback(this, callback);`

Comment: So what you want is that every time your back button is pressed in a fragment you want a callback in your fragment?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how callbacks work. What I'm trying to do is be able to use a specific  method when the OnBackPressed() event fires in a specific fragment. So, for example, fragment A would execute method A when OnBackPressed() fires, while fragment B would execute method B when OnBackPressed() fires.

Comment: I see updating my answer...