# Xamarin.Android predictive back gesture (OnBackPressed deprecated)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In Android 13 the OnBackPressed method [has become deprecated](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/predictive-back-gesture#java). How can i implement this code in Xamarin.Android?

```
@Override
void onCreate() {
  if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastT()) {
    getOnBackInvokedDispatcher().registerOnBackInvokedCallback(
        OnBackInvokedDispatcher.PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
        () -> {
          /**
          * Code here
          */
        }
    );
  }
}
```

The code above is the Java example from the official android dev website, but i can't find the replacements for this in Xamarin.
Can someone translate this to C#?

This is what Visual studio suggests, but it doesn't help at all.

```
Warning CS0672:Member 'MainActivity.OnBackPressed()' overrides obsolete member 'Activity.OnBackPressed()'. Add the Obsolete attribute to 'MainActivity.OnBackPressed()'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [OnBackPressedDispatcher.AddCallback()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher#addCallback(androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback))

**MainAcivity.cs**

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (BuildCompat.IsAtLeastT)
        {
        OnBackPressedDispatcher.AddCallback(new CustomOnBackPressed(true));
        }
```

**CustomOnBackPressed.cs**

```
public class CustomOnBackPressed : OnBackPressedCallback
{
    public OnBack(bool enabled) : base(enabled)
    {
    }

    public override void HandleOnBackPressed()
    {
        //code that handles back button pressed
    }
}
```

#### Related question

[onBackPressed() deprecated, What is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72634225/5228202)

Comment: This code kind of works, but when i add android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true" to AndroidManifest.xml as adviced in [android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/predictive-back-gesture), the custom functionality no longer happens. I haven't researched that much about the predictive back gesture so that might be the right outcome, but the custom code at least does not work.

Comment: i see in VS that MAUI is supporting up to API 32 for now, while what you linked has been added in android API 33. could be the reason also why i cannot find `OnBackInvokedCallback()`

Comment: this is not for MAUI its for Xamarin.Android

Answer (score 0):

There are a series of Xamarin.Android tutorials using the NavigationComponent at https://github.com/gmck. As you progress through the projects, you will see the introduction of OnBackPressedCallback which is used extensively in the later projects.