# Proper usage of OnBackPressedDispatcher

Tags: android

Sometimes, I want to handle the back button being pressed by the user myself. My (example) code looks something like this:

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.test)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {

        if (checkSomeCondition()) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    private fun checkSomeCondition() = false
}
```

I get notified when back is pressed, and then I decide if I want to handle it, or let the system handle it by calling `super.onBackPressed()`.

Since onBackPressed() is now [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed()), I replace it by using the `OnBackPressedDispatcher`:

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.test)

        onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                if (checkSomeCondition()) {
                    // do nothing
                } else {
                    onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun checkSomeCondition() = false
}
```

The problem with this code: by calling `onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()`, I **call my own callback, creating an infinite loop** instead of handing this over to the system like I would with `super.onBackPressed()`.

This can be circumvented when temporarily disabling my callback like:

```
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            if (checkSomeCondition()) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                this.isEnabled = false
                onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
                this.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    })
```

but that seems rather awkward and doesn't seem like it was intended that way.

What's the correct usage of the `OnBackPressedDispatcher` here that lets me either handle the back button press myself **or** hand it over to the system?

PS: I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72634225/onbackpressed-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative) question about the deprecation of onBackPressed, but it doesn't answer my much more specific question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [Basics of System Back video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Elpqr5xpLxQ), the whole point of the [Predictive Back gesture](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/predictive-back-gesture) is to know **ahead of time** what is going to handle back.

That means that you should **never** have just-in-time logic such as `checkSomeCondition` as part of your call to `handleOnBackPressed`.

Instead, as explained in the [Custom back navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back), you should be updating the `isEnabled` state of your `OnBackPressedCallback` **ahead of time** whenever the conditions you used to check in `checkSomeCondition` changed. This ensures that your callback is only invoked when your condition is already true and is disabled when the condition is false, thus allowing the default behavior to occur.

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.test)

        // Instead of always setting enabled to true at the beginning,
        // you need to check the state ahead of time to know what the
        // initial enabled state should be
        val isConditionAlreadySet = checkSomeCondition()
        val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(
            isConditionAlreadySet
        ) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                // Since you've handled isEnabled correctly, you know
                // your condition is set correctly here, so you can
                // unconditionally do what you need to do to handle back
            }
        }
        // This is the key part - now you know ahead of time
        // when the condition changes, which lets you control
        // when you want to handle back or not
        setOnSomeConditionChangedListener { isConditionMet ->
          callback.isEnabled = isConditionMet
        }
        onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, callback)
    }

    private fun checkSomeCondition() = false
    private fun setOnSomeConditionChangedListener(
        (isConditionMet: Boolean) -> Unit
    ) {
        // The implementation here will depend on what
        // conditions checkSomeCondition() actually depends on
    }

}
```

Comment: @ianhanniballake , I understand the new ahead-of-time approach. It suggests either a custom back callback OR system back handling. However, what if I want a custom back callback AND system back handling? 
For instance, I want to intervene in the system back handling and run "Analytics.track("BACK_PRESSED")" before the system's behavior. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @irfano - you cannot do that. You can add your analytics to the `onDestroy` method though - using `isFinishing()` (in an Activity) or `isRemoving()` (in a Fragment) to know when you are being popped.

Comment: What if i want to use overridePendingTransition? i wan to use the defaultbackpresseddispatcher and add pendingtransition. That wont work in onDestroy

Comment: @wiryadev - Predictive Back is exactly why `overridePendingTransition` is deprecated in API 34 - it's replacement, [`overrideActivityTranstion`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#overrideActivityTransition(int,%20int,%20int)) is specifically designed to allow you to set the transition ahead of time, without needing to intercept back at all.

Comment: Is that already backported? I couldnt find any mention of that in Jetpack Activity release note

Comment: There can be use cases where we need conditional handling of onBackPress - For example, if user is interacting with a certain view - a certain view is in focus I want to handle the backpress, where as in normal scenario, I want Android OS to handle backpress. what should I do in that case?, Is there a better way to handle that instead enabling and disabling like the OP did.

Comment: @ahmed - you would call [`setOnFocusChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setOnFocusChangeListener(android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener)) on your View, enabling your `OnBackPressedCallback` when the view becomes focused and disabling it when your view is no longer focused.

Comment: @ianhanniballake `overrideActivityTransition` doesn't really work. Or at least I couldn't find a reliable way to use it, no proper examples or explanations on how to use it either. Also, the documentation contradicts what you're saying: "And if we want to customize the closing transition when finishing Activity B and back to Activity A, since B is still is above A, we should call this method in Activity B with overrideType = OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_CLOSE.". Can you please share and example or link to an **useful** docs? Share the wisdom please.

Comment: @shadox - you'll want to post a separate question with the code you've tried. The simplest code (calling `overrideActivityTransition` twice (once to set the enter transition and once to set the exit transition) in `onCreate`) should give you a working starting point.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have posted this couple of days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77883747/activity-transition-animations

Comment: @ianhanniballake Why change a simple onBackPressed call to such a complex solution? I cannot wrap my head around the benefits that might come from such approach. Could you shed some light on why it was changed?

Comment: if I don't need this `enabled` state, what if I know that I always should do some action in on back pressed callback which don't depend on any state?

Answer (score 0):

As we can't use `onBackPressedDispatcher` for triggering default back pressed behavior after execution our action, there is another solution to get both for newer Android (`onBackInvokedDispatcher`) versions on older ones (`onBackPressed` still can be used for older versions):

in Manifest:

```
<application
    android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
```

In Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        onBackInvokedDispatcher.registerOnBackInvokedCallback(1000) {
            onBackAction()
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}

@Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        onBackAction()
    }
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    super.onBackPressed()
}

private fun onBackAction() {
    // your action
    // p.s. if you use it for compose screen logic, 
    // the just implement some logic to check
    // current screen based on current navController's route
}
```