# Activity transition animations

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I am trying to do some simple animations on activity transition. When I start activity B from activity A, I want activity A to leave the screen to the left and activity B to slide in from the right.

After digging into the documentation, I have found this formula:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34) {
        overrideActivityTransition(
                ComponentActivity.OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_OPEN,
                R.anim.slide_in_from_right,
                R.anim.slide_out_left
            )
        } else overridePendingTransition(
            R.anim.slide_in_from_right,
            R.anim.slide_out_left
        )
```

In my project, most of the time (when SDK < 34), it kinda' works. Activity B slides in from the right and activity A, after flickering and changing it's background color to white, disappears.

Here's the code:

**Attempt 1** (T1Screen is just a text with a button NEXT)

```
class T1Activity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AndroidMex4Theme {
                T1Screen() { startNextActivity() }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startNextActivity() {
        startActivity(Intent(this@T1Activity, T2Activity::class.java))
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 34) overridePendingTransition(
            R.anim.slide_in_from_right,
            R.anim.slide_out_left,
        ) else overrideActivityTransition(
            OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_OPEN,
            R.anim.slide_in_from_right,
            R.anim.slide_out_left,
        )
    }
}
```

**Attempt 2** (T2Screen is the same as T1Screen):

```
class T2Activity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34) {
            overrideActivityTransition(
                OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_OPEN,
                R.anim.slide_in_from_right,
                R.anim.slide_out_left,
            )
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            AndroidMex4Theme {
                T2Screen { startNextActivity() }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Method `overrideActivityTransition` doesn't work as expected. I've made it work once but couldn't repeat the performance. Moreover, I need to use flags like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` to clear the backstack and it adds to the confusion.

While `overridePendingTransition` is working, it is deprecated.

When SDK = 34, activity B slides from left to right, on top of activity A. I haven't figured out what `overrideActivityTransition` really does or what `OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_OPEN` or `OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_CLOSE` really means. I was expecting it to work for API 34 but it does something else. After multiple trials and errors I'm still stuck with this.

Here are the animations:

**slide_in_from_right**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="300">

        <translate
            android:fromXDelta="100%"
            android:toXDelta="0%"
     />
     </set>
```

**slide_out_left**

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="300">
        <translate
            android:fromXDelta="0"
            android:toXDelta="-100%"
        />
    </set>
```

I've tried few other things but nothing seems to work.

P.S. Oh yes, I want to do that in reverse too, when pressing back button. I have the animations defined but not sure about the rest.

Answer (score 1):

This is a BUG in the system, upgrading from android 13 to Android 14 requires the user to restart the phone, otherwise the activity transition animation will be abnormal. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/300310597

Answer (score 0):

There is two solution for this problem;

1.) You can change the animation for every Activity open and close animations and to do that you need to change your manifest file like this

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
  <!-- enable window content transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>

  <!-- specify enter and exit transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/explode</item>
  <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/explode</item>

  <!-- specify shared element transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
  <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
</style>
```

for the official answer you can check this [link](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/transitions/start-activity).

2.This is the more basic solution it will only change animation only for 1 activity and here is a way to do it.

This is for opening animation.

```
startActivity();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.fade_in);
```

For closing animation you can use like this

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Comment: In your answer, at number 1, that's `styles.xml` **not** `manifest.xml`. Also copying & pasting from docs isn't helpful either, unless you add something useful.

Comment: At number 2, what's `R.anim.hold`? I might be able to come up with something myself but if you're trying to help, please specify it explicitly. Otherwise I have to guess - what's the point then?

Comment: Forgot to mention, my issue was mostly around `overrideActivityTransition` not the deprecated `overridePendingTransition`. I'll edit the question if that wasn't clear enough.